# declare a variable to ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

In PowerShell, i want declare a variable to ffmpeg:

```
## DOSSIERS DE TRAVAIL
$Ingest = "C:\INGEST\" ## DOSSIER WATCHE
$outPath = "C:\TRANSCODE\" ## DOSSIER DE DESTINATION, A definir
$TEMP = "C:\temp\" ## dossier temporaire de récupération des essences (de-wrapp fichier ingesté) 
 

$MAPaudio = ""
$Filesaudio = ""


for ($i = 1; $i -le $nombreAudios; $i++) {
    $TEMP_AUDIO = $TEMP + "audio" + $i + ".wav"
    ##Extraction de l'audio et conversion en 48000hz (Obligatoire pour le MXF)
    $MAPaudio += " -map " + $i + ":a "
    $Filesaudio += " -i " + $TEMP_AUDIO
}

    
$TEMP_VIDEO = $TEMP + "video.mxf"

write-host $MAPaudio
write-host $Filesaudio
##Encapsulage de la vidéo
$result = " -i $TEMP_VIDEO $Filesaudio -c copy -map 0:v:0 $MAPaudio -y c:\transcode\test.mxf".tostring()
  
ffmpeg "$result"
```

I have an error:

```
Output #0, mxf, to ' -i C:\temp\video.mxf  -i C:\temp\audio1.wav -i C:\temp\audio2.wav -i C:\temp\audio3.wav -i C:\temp\audio4.wav -c copy -map 0:v:0  -map 1:a  -map 2:a  -map 3:a  -map 4:a  -y c:\transcode\test.mxf':
```

Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Yet, if i give the variable to ffmpeg without powershell, it works !!!
I don't understand why, ffmpeg doesn't want my variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively calling `ffmpeg` like this:

```sh
ffmpeg " -i $TEMP_VIDEO $Filesaudio -c copy -map 0:v:0 $MAPaudio -y c:\transcode\test.mxf"
```

Note the double quotes that are *automatically* added by PowerShell, when you pass a variable that contains whitespace, as an argument to a native command!

As a result, `ffmpeg` sees only a single argument, that it doesn't understand.

If you want to store multiple arguments in a variable, it has to be an *array* instead of a single string. PowerShell unrolls and quotes (as necessary) the individual arguments, when passing the arrays to the command.

To fix the code:

```sh
$TEMP = "C:\temp" ## dossier temporaire de récupération des essences (de-wrapp fichier ingesté) 
 
$MAPaudio = @()    # create empty array
$Filesaudio = @()  # create empty array

for ($i = 1; $i -le $nombreAudios; $i++) {
    $TEMP_AUDIO = Join-Path $TEMP "audio$i.wav"
    ##Extraction de l'audio et conversion en 48000hz (Obligatoire pour le MXF)

    # Append two elements to the argument array
    $MAPaudio += "-map", "${i}:a"

    # Append two elements to the argument array
    $Filesaudio += "-i", $TEMP_AUDIO
}
    
$TEMP_VIDEO = Join-Path $TEMP "video.mxf"

# Finally pass the arguments separately, instead of a single string
ffmpeg -i $TEMP_VIDEO $Filesaudio -c copy -map 0:v:0 $MAPaudio -y 'c:\transcode\test.mxf'
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already try your answer but i ahve another error: -i C:\temp\audio1.wav -i C:\temp\audio2.wav -i C:\temp\audio3.wav -i C:\temp\audio4.wav: Invalid argument

Comment: @EricGouezec Yes, I already noticed there are more problems and just fixed them.

Comment: I thank that ffmpeg doesn't like receive variable with powershell

Comment: @EricGouezec I've fixed a few more issues, please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I test this:

```
   ##Récupération et formatage du nom de la vidéo
$name=[string]$_
$nameFileToEncode=$name.split('.')[-2]
$nameFileToEncode=$nameFileToEncode.replace(" ","_")

##Path complet de la Video de sortie
$outVideo="$outPath"+"\"+"$nameFileToEncode"+".mxf"


$MAPaudio=""
$Filesaudio=""


for($i=1;$i -le $nombreAudios;$i++)
{
$TEMP_AUDIO=$TEMP+"audio"+$i+".wav"
##Extraction de l'audio et conversion en 48000hz (Obligatoire pour le MXF)
$MAPaudio += " -map "+$i+":a "
$Filesaudio +=" -i "+ $TEMP_AUDIO
}


$TEMP_VIDEO=$TEMP+"video.mxf"

write-host $MAPaudio
write-host $Filesaudio
##Encapsulage de la vidéo
```

`&ffmpeg -i $TEMP_VIDEO $Filesaudio -c copy -map 0:v:0 $MAPaudio -y 'c:\transcode\test.mxf'`

but i have this error:

```
Output #0, wav, to ' -i C:\temp\audio1.wav -i C:\temp\audio2.wav -i C:\temp\audio3.wav -i C:\temp\audio4.wav':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Curiously, it says that is a output then this is inputs...